# how to fix Exception: Request failed for https://docs.google.com returned code 400

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

It sometimes submits successfully, sometimes doesn't.

**Exception**: Request failed for https://docs.google.com returned code 400. Truncated server response: <link rel="shortcut icon" sizes="16x16" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/spreadsheets/forms/favic... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)

My google apps script code:

```js
function auto_data_entry() {
  
  var formURL="https://docs.google.com/forms/u/0/d/e/1FAIpQLSdCyw4T7KUyhs31YS0vB6sKJTjdpivzJtPsMoPlGEcmt7n8Lw/formResponse";

  var wrkBk = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var wrkSht = wrkBk.getSheetByName('Sheet2');

  var rm = wrkSht.getRange("A2").getValue();
  var storeid = wrkSht.getRange("B2").getValue();
  var storename = wrkSht.getRange("C2").getValue();
  var skuid = wrkSht.getRange("D2").getValue();
  var brand = wrkSht.getRange("E2").getValue();
  var skuname = wrkSht.getRange("F2").getValue();
  var stockonhand = wrkSht.getRange("G2").getValue();
  var rsp = wrkSht.getRange("H2").getValue();
  var psp = wrkSht.getRange("I2").getValue();

  var datamap={"entry.214978149":storeid,
  "entry.553766417": rm,
  "entry.1889230843": storename,
  "entry.1312164911": skuid,
  "entry.1558403391": brand,
  "entry.1736637790": skuname,
  "entry.618017708": stockonhand,
  "entry.1026403067": rsp,
  "entry.18794913": psp};

  var options = {
      "method": "post",
      "payload": datamap
  };

  UrlFetchApp.fetch(formURL, options);

}
```

Comment: Apologies, but I'm not familiar with the post request you are trying to do. Could you edit your post and include what is the goal of your script and the references you've used for the post request?